# Métodos do UITableViewDelegate não são chamados com o SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, framework

Tenho um `UITableView` que representa um menu usando o framework [`SWRevealViewController`](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). Os métodos que requerem interação com o usuário não estão funcionando corretamente.

Por exemplo: o método `didSelectRowAtIndex` dificilmente funciona e o `didHighLightRowAtIndex` só funciona se pressionar por muito tempo.

Atualização: com UITableViewController funciona perfeitamente, o problema está em que eu tenho que usar um UIViewController com um UITableViewController dentro.

Comment: Se esses *delegates* sequer estão sendo chamados, não acredito que tenha relação com a biblioteca já que esta tabela é apenas uma `UITableViewController`, certo? Você tem algum código para mostrar? É possível detalhar mais o problema? Eu utilizo essa mesma biblioteca e não tenho problemas neste ponto.

Comment: heightForRowAtIndex por exemplo esta sendo chamado, o didHighlightRowAtIndex tamben pode ser chamado, ainda que con algo de dificuldade. O didSelectRowAtIndex básicamente não é chamado. algo de relacão terá com o framework